# Axios POST Request only logged after page is refreshed and not functioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

recently I tried to familiarize myself with React Native.

I found that the POST request for my login method only logged in after the page is refreshed. The POST message also seems like it has been stalled. Unfortunately, this error only occurs on my PC environment, not on my friend's PC.

I'm not sure what is the factor that causes this issues. Would love if anyone had any idea why this only appear on certain PC environment.

[image: How the POST request logs inside the terminal]

**Login.js**

```
handleLoginFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    axios
      .post("/users/login", {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          message: "success",
          isLoggedIn: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
          username: "",
          password: "",
          message: `${err.response.data}`
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Problem is somewhere else.. why it is calling isLoggedIn get API?

Comment: That's other issue I think that's not related to this matter.. @souravsatyam. Because other people also have those errors and can run the login just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need async await, because fetching data need uncertain time

Add async on this line

handleLoginFormSubmit = async (e} =>

And await on this line

await axios

Comment: I already added both of of those, but it still won't work. Not sure if related to that because my colleague able to run this code perfectly. @i-p